Docker: Error response from daemon: could not select device driver "nvidia" with capabilities:
I am attempting to run various applications that are using a nvidia GPU from docker containers. I am running on a machine with the following configuration:
 /0/0                             memory         64KiB BIOS
/0/32                            memory         64GiB System Memory
...
/0/37                            processor      AMD Ryzen 7 1700 Eight-Core Processor
...

I am running on Ubuntu 24.04.
I have installed the nvidia CUDA toolkit:
sudo apt install nvidia-cuda-toolkit

but when I attempt to start an application, for exaqmple stable-diffusion:
docker compose --profile auto up --build

I get the following failure:
Error response from daemon: could not select device driver "nvidia" with capabilities: [[compute utility]]

I have seen similar posts where the capabilities are "gpu", but the solutions provided for those problems are dated and they don't resolve this specific issue (where the capabilities are "compute" and "utility".
Could someone explain what these failures mean and (more importantly) how to fix them?

Problem is solved.
I had installed the nvidia drivers after installing Docker (https://docs.nvidia.com/datacenter/cloud-native/container-toolkit/latest/install-guide.html#installing-the-nvidia-container-toolkit). After installing the drivers, I forgot to restart the docker daemon:
sudo systemctl restart docker

Once I restarted the daemon, this particular failure went away.
Unfortunately, I am experiencing another failure that is pretty consistent. Some kind of initialization error. It is not appropriate to discuss this new problem here, so I will post it to a new venue.
